# How to get max/min of list of 2d array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

i have a list of 2d array like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        List<int[,]> kidsL = new List<int[,]>();
        int[,] square1 = new int[8, 8];
        int[,] square2 = new int[8, 8];
        int[,] square3 = new int[8, 8];
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                square1[i, j] = 1;
                square2[i, j] = 2;
                square3[i, j] = 3;
            }
        kidsL.Add(square1);
        kidsL.Add(square2);
        kidsL.Add(square3);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Read();
    }
```

i want to determine sum of every array and find the maxamim/minimum one (in this case the maximum one is 192).

is there an easy way to do this or am I just going to have to loop through the old fashioned way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use the following code to get `IEnumarable<int>` from `int[,]`

```
var enumarable = from int item in square2
                 select item;
```

Also, you can use a `Cast<int>()` method in order to unwrap `int[,]` to `IEnumarable<int>`.

Then you can use `Max()` and `Min()` linq method.

```
var min = kidsL.Min(x => (from int item in x select item).Sum());
var max = kidsL.Max(x => (from int item in x select item).Sum());
// or
var min = kidsL.Min(x => x.Cast<int>().Sum())
```

or

```
var Max = (from int[,] array in kidsL
           select (from int item in array select item).Sum())
          .Max();
```

**Update**

`from int[,] array in kidsL select (from int item in array select item).Sum()` query returns you an `IEnumarable<int>` which contains sums. In order to have the index of max, you should cast IEnumarable to array or list using `ToList` or `ToArray()`.

```
var sumList = (from int[,] array in kidsL
               select(from int item in array select item).Sum())
               .ToList();

var maxSum = sumList.Max();
var maxInd = sumList.IndexOf(maxSum);
```

`sumList` is a list of ints and contains sums. So then you can use `Max` method to get max sum and  `IndexOf` to get index of the max.

Comment: I support this answer, this looks simple. But the Execution rate is slower since you have to access IEnumerable and use Linq as well. But it is Cleaner than the for loop. I doubt that there is a faster way than the for loop cause IEnumerable also executes in a for loop.

Comment: @MehrdadKamali just a moment

Comment: @Valentin thank you so much, look likes a lot easier than looping, but does it any change in performance?

Comment: and one more thing: how can i get the index of that array in method 2...for example in this case (max=192), index of the list is 2

Comment: @MehrdadKamali It won't change the asymptotic behavior of the complexity. You won't see a difference especially for 8x8 matrices.

Comment: @Valentin So i should work with this since i don't have any other option. Thanks again for your great help.

Answer (score 2):

`Cast<int>` method will flatten array to `IEnumerable<int>` which allows using LINQ.

```
var max = kidsL.Max(square => square.Cast<int>().Sum());
var min = kidsL.Min(square => square.Cast<int>().Sum());
```

You should also be aware of possible overflow which can happen if values and dimensions of the array would be large.

> is there an easy way to do this or am I just going to have to loop through the old fashioned way?

Although the solution is concise it has the same efficiency as looping over every element of every array. But that's indeed is an easy way.

Comment: when i paste into my program, it's shows me an error like this: 'Queryable.Cast<TResult>(IQueryable)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context. BTW i'm not a professorial.

Comment: @Mehrdad Kamali, yes you are right. Check out code after edits.