# How to get max/min of list of 2d array in java

Tags: java, arrays, linq, arraylist

I was asked the same question for c# [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35998706/how-to-get-max-min-of-list-of-2d-array-in-c-sharp) and I figured out by using linq you can do this easily.

But how can I simply do this since there is no alternative for linq in java?

Comment: seems like duplicate question. refer this link -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452190/min-and-max-value-in-2d-array-java

Comment: You could use a sorting algorithm, which would make the first element of your array the min, and the last element the max. You can also look into using lambda expressions, if you convert your array to be a `List`.

Comment: This is a good beginner programming problem. Why don't you give it a try? Start with 1d array first.

Comment: @Teja I don't think so, i have a list of 2d-arrays

Comment: @LoganKulinski I did the first solution cause unfortunately my IDE doesn't support lanbda expressions.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Well thanks. But I'm kind of in a hurry so ... :)

Comment: @MehrdadKamali which IDE are you using? The ability to use lambdas shouldn't depend on your IDE. It should depend on what version of the JDK you are using.

Comment: @LoganKulinski I use PDE (Processing Development Environment) and as far as I know it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something similar to LINQ, you can do this using Java8 streams:

```
// prepare arrays
List<int[][]> kidsL = new ArrayList<>();
int[][] square1 = new int[8][8];
int[][] square2 = new int[8][8];
int[][] square3 = new int[8][8];
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        square1[i][j] = 1;
        square2[i][j] = 2;
        square3[i][j] = 3;
    }
kidsL.add(square1);
kidsL.add(square2);
kidsL.add(square3);

// find min
kidsL.stream()
        .mapToInt(a -> Arrays.stream(a).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).sum())
        .min()
        .ifPresent(System.err::println);

// find max
kidsL.stream()
        .mapToInt(a -> Arrays.stream(a).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).sum())
        .max()
        .ifPresent(System.err::println);
```

It prints:

```
64
192
```

But it is less effective than simple for loops, because you calculating the sum two times.

Of course you can add intermediate operation to store the list of sums, and then calculate min/max based on that.

```
// intermediate list of sums
List<Integer> sums = kidsL.stream()
        .mapToInt(a -> Arrays.stream(a).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).sum())
        .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

sums.stream().mapToInt(i -> i)
        .min()
        .ifPresent(System.err::println);

sums.stream().mapToInt(i -> i)
        .max()
        .ifPresent(System.err::println);
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly the thing i want. But unfortunately the IDE (Processing Environment) doesn't support lambda expressions...so I'll should go for other solution I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is unsorted, the only real way to find the min and max is to iterate through the whole thing.

```
int[][] array = new int[10][10];
int min = array[0][0];
int max = array[0][0];
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++){
        if(array[i][j] < min){
            min = array[i][j];
        }
        if(array[i][j] > max){
            max = array[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

I just reread the question, and I think you mean an `ArrayList<int[][]>` which would be:

```
ArrayList<int[][]> arrayList = new ArrayList<int[][]>();

int min = arrayList.get(0)[0][0];
int max = arrayList.get(0)[0][0];

for(int[][] array : arrayList){
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++){
            if(array[i][j] < min){
                min = array[i][j];
            }
            if(array[i][j] > max){
                max = array[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: However it's not exactly what i want.(I need to store sum of each 2d-arrays in a list and then find the max and min in that list). But with some modification, I solved my problem thanks to you